# Java: Inheriting method with return type

Tags: java, inheritance, return

The `Class3` class extends to `Class1` class. In `Class3`, the method should return the total of the bonus and the salary and Class1 inherits from `Class3` and displays the total and calculates the yearly salary by multiplying the total by 12.  The problem is that the output which is I am getting for the total and `yearlySalary` is 0.0.

Here are the codes:

```
class MyClass extends MyClass3{
    double yearlySalary = 12.0*total;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass obj1 = new MyClass();

        System.out.println("Employee's salary is: "+ obj1.salary);
        System.out.println("Employee's bonus is: "+ obj1.bonus);
        System.out.println("Total: "+ obj1.total);
        System.out.println("Yearly Salary: "+ obj1.yearlySalary);
    }
}
```

Second class:

```
public class MyClass3 { 
    double salary =40000;
    double bonus = 2000;
    double total;       

    public double CalcTotal(){
        total = salary+bonus;
        return total;
    }
}
```

Comment: you are never calling `CalcTotal()`

Comment: Correction `System.out.println("Total: "+ obj1.CalcTotal());`

Comment: @Max Zoom It works either way.. Thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never called CalcTotal().
Try this:

```
class MyClass extends MyClass3{


        double yearlySalary= 12.0*CalcTotal();

        public static void main(String[] args) {

         MyClass obj1= new MyClass();



         System.out.println("Employee's salary is: "+ obj1.salary);
         System.out.println("Employee's bonus is: "+ obj1.bonus);
         System.out.println("Total: "+ obj1.total);
         System.out.println("Yearly Salary: "+ obj1.yearlySalary);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You never call `CalcTotal()`.

You must also ensure that you call it *before* the `yearlySalary` value is calculated.